# How do i set `setOnDateChangedListener` into `MaterialDatePicker` in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, changelistener, materialdatepicker

I've used MaterialDatePicker which has package: com.google.android.material.datepicker

I date picked successfully from MaterialDatePicker, when I set addOnPositiveButtonClickListener

But my requirement is I need to get a date when the date changed in the dialog

yes, DatePickerDialog has the method that return me date when date was changed by user, but I need implement into MaterialDatePicker, how can I?